# explain strange jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was exercising at http://jqexercise.droppages.com/#page_0016_ and after completing the exercise "Change the h2 to h3" I checked out the answer by pressing "Give up?" and I saw this:

```
var target = $('#target');
target.html(target.html().replace(/h2/g,'h3'));
```

Does anyone has a clue how this .replace(/h2/g,'h3') "selector" works?

I did not find anything about .replace() , maybe deprecated. But even when I found .replaceWith() I did not find any references to this selector that looks like reg ex with escape character.

If you can explain or point to something to read about this I would be grade full.

Comment: `replace` is a method of javascript `String` object - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: I got it. so this is not jquery but pure JavaScript with a regex.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually if I am correct /h2/ is regex expression. So anything between // is taken and replaced with string after comma. g is flag to apply matching globally.

You can read exactly about it on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a jQuery selector but regular function of javascript replace https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

where /h2/g as first parameter is just a regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `target.html()` is going to return a string, and then `string.replace` part is going to do a regex replace and return a string too. And then `target.html(string)` is going to set the outerhtml of the target to the modified one.